# CSS - Change sub class background image on hover

Tags: asp.net, css

I have the following code for a selectable tab:

```
<div class="tabOff">
   <div class="lightCorner TL"></div><div class="lightCorner TR"></div>
   <div class="cornerBoxInner">
      <p>My Tab</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

On the mouse over of tabOff I have the following CSS for changing the background colour:

```
.tabOff:hover
{
    background:#AAA;
    color:#CDEB8B;
}
```

Is there any way I can change my classes "lightCorner TL" and "lightCorner TR" to use a different background image, without JavaScript, when tabOff is hovered

This is the current CSS for lightCorner TL and TR:

```
.lightCorner
{
    background:url(../Images/LightCorner.gif) no-repeat;
}
.TL
{
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background-position:0px 0px;
}
.TR
{
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    background-position:-13px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have never tried it, but I would start with:

```
.tabOff:hover .lightCorner {
}
```

Don´t know if that's correct usage though.

Comment: That works great for a start, but I need to control the TL and TR corners separately. Thanks!

Comment: Scrap that, got it working with your example, just replace .lightCorner with .TR!

Comment: Well, just try it with .tabOff:hover .TR {} and .tabOff:hover .TL {}, the above was just an example.

Comment: Note that earlier versions of IE don't handle :hover correctly on non-'a' elements.

Comment: @Sam DeFabbia-Kane: True, but as the OP already is using :hover on div's I guess IE6 is not a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```
.tabOff:hover div.lightCorner {
  background:url(../Images/LightCorner.gif) no-repeat;
}
.tabOff:hover div.TL {
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  background-position:0px 0px;
}
.tabOff:hover div.TR {
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  background-position:-13px 0px;
}
```